# How to name a file using variable and returning the filename

Tags: java, file

My objective is to create a method in which a user inputs their first name and last name, and with this information a .txt file will be created and named using the first initial of the first name and the last name. For example if user enter Marcus Simmon, the text file created should be named "MSimmon.txt" and how would I be able to return this file name. Thank you in advance. This is my code so far...

```
public static String GetUserInfo() {
    // complete with your code of the method GetUserInfo
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your first name: ");
    char initial = input.next().charAt(0);
    System.out.println("Please enter your last name: ");
    String lastName = input.nextLine();

    try{
        FileWriter x = new FileWriter(initial + lastName + ".txt");
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("ERROR");
    }

}
```

Comment: Does simply `return initial + lastName + ".txt";` meet your requirements?

Comment: Are you getting errors?  What does `initial + lastName + ".txt"` evaluate to in the code?

Comment: Thank you! It seems to work! One more question, will this create 2 files if I only add the return initial + lastName + ".txt" to the existing code? @KenY-N

Comment: No it won't. A file is only created when you explicitly call a function that creates a file, such as `FileWriter()` above.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much